# Extracting specific parts of a log file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a program that runs a several utilities on a nightly basis.  This utility outputs each action it takes to the same log file each night.  The log is cumulative so I have thousands of lines to sort through.  Here is a sample:

10/15/2014  08:19:43  [Nightly Run] began. 
10/15/2014  08:19:44  Start Header Check at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014 
10/15/2014  08:19:44      Unable to read header - [Filepath] 
10/15/2014  08:19:46  End Header Check at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014 
10/15/2014  08:19:47  [Utility 1] began 
10/15/2014  08:20:14  [Utility 1] ended 
10/15/2014  08:20:18  [Utility 2] began. 
10/15/2014  08:20:18  [Utility 2] ended. 
10/15/2014  08:20:33  [Nightly Run] ended.

the header check occurs on a nightly basis so there are hundreds of lines to go through.  The "unable to read header" error does not occur every night.  I am trying to output the nights that the header is erroring to a text file, basically I would like my output to read as

10/15/2014  08:19:44  Start Header Check at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014 
10/15/2014  08:19:44      Unable to read header - [Filepath] 
10/15/2014  08:19:46  End Header Check at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014

for each time the header check runs AND errors on a specific [Filepath].

My thought is to break the text up into separate objects based on "Start Header Check"/"End Header Check" and use a select-string to grab only the objects containing "Unable to read header - [Filepath]".

```
    Get-content X:\logfile.txt -delimiter "Start Header Check" |
    Select-String -Pattern 'Unable to read header - [Filepath]' |
    out-file X:\outfile.txt
```

Which returns:

at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014 
10/15/2014  08:19:44      Unable to read header - [Filepath] 
10/15/2014  08:19:46  End Header Check at 8:19 AM on 10/15/2014 
10/15/2014  08:19:47  [Utility 1] began 
10/15/2014  08:20:14  [Utility 1] ended 
10/15/2014  08:20:18  [Utility 2] began. 
10/15/2014  08:20:18  [Utility 2] ended. 
10/15/2014  08:20:33  [Nightly Run] ended.

It cuts out most of the runs I don't want but I still have alot of extra info I don't need.  I can see why it returns this but I can't figure out a way around it.  I would imagine that regex has to be involved somehow but I've not used regex in years.

I did consider using the -raw switch for the -raw parameter and using .slipt() but I'm pretty sure I was barking up the wrong tree with that.

I'm flat stuck, been trying different tweaks all morning and I haven't really made progress.  I would list everything I've tried but i don't want to muddy the waters.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can do:  cat <log_file> | grep "Unable to read header" -A 1 -B 1. You can add another pipe with wc to get the line count but you need to remove A and B from grep something like: cat <log_file> | grep "Unable to read header" | wc -l

Comment: @FarhanRahman: How do you do that with Powershell? It's highly advisable to read the tags before posting to a question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by using `Get-Content -Delimiter '[Nightly Run]` ended.

That will break it up into groups of lines for each run.  Each group will be a single, multi-line string.  Extract the relevant lines from each group using a multi-line regex:

```
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)[0-9/]+ [0-9:]+ Start Header Check at .+? 
.+? Unable to read header .+
.+? End Header Check .+? on [0-9/]+
'@

Get-content X:\logfile.txt -delimiter '[Nightly Run] ended.' |
foreach {
 if ($_ -match $regex)
  { $Matches[0] }
 }
```

Edit: regex adjusted for possibility of multiple read failures.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks.  It was that multiline regex that was holding me up.  Haven't used those since my Everquest days with ACT.

Comment: Bah, shot myself in the foot by not fully explaining the log in the initial post.  There are instances where that header fails across multiple files.  What would the regex be to include multiple lines?  Gonna try on my own for a bit but if you are feeling doubly helpful.  :)
10/31/2014  07:15:42  Start Header Check at 7:15 AM on 10/31/2014
10/31/2014  07:15:42      Unable to read header - File 1
10/31/2014  07:15:42      Unable to read header - File 2
10/31/2014  07:15:42      Unable to read header - File 3
10/31/2014  07:15:44  End Header Check at 7:15 AM on 10/31/2014

Comment: Update the answer.  Does that handle the multiple failures? Edit: I see you added more data to the comment.  Working on it.

Comment: OK.  I adjusted the regex.  It was actually a trivial change to get it to capture multiple failure lines.

Comment: There is something slightly off with that regex.  Specifically the "[0-9/]+ [0-9:]+"" part.  If i run the script with that in place I get no returns.  If I replace that with ".+" I get returns but the delimiter line is pulled from the log...weird.  As far as I'm concerned the script is working well enough but I'd like to learn what is going on with that line, if you know.  Mostly what does the (?ms) part do?

Comment: The  "[0-9/]+ [0-9:]+" should match your date and time stamps at the beginning of the line (it matched when I ran it against your posted test data). Basically it matches "one or more of the characters 0 to 9 or /, followed by a space and then one or more of the characters 0 to 9 or :. The (?ms) at the beginning makes it a multi-line single-line regex, which lets you put it into a here-string and use embedded newlines. This makes it visually similar to the data record, rather than one long line with explicit newlines in the match string.

Comment: Figured it out, the log actually has a double space between the date and time.  This didn't translate to the data I provided above (not sure why, I did a straight copy/paste) but when I added the extra space to the regex, it cleared everything up.  Thanks for the further explanation, led me right to it.  I appreciate all the help!